# Using inline SVG with CSS/Less

Tags: css, svg, less

I am stuck on a problem that can be solved by duplicating lots of content but I am hoping to avoid this.

I am using an array from the database of products to generate content blocks, and colour of the background is in here. So in this instance I use inline CSS to generate the background colour from this. HOwever Each content block requires SVGs appropriately colour co-ordinated.

I realise I can use `fill:#fff` to change the colour of these SVGs, however I can't do this inline a the SVGs are retrieved via php's `file_get_contents`

Everything else I could just do `color:parent` however parent doesn't work on `fill`.

What would be the best approach to have the SVGs colour change to the appropriate colour of its product content block?

I am using .LESS also and thought it may be possbible to set a colour inline that could be used but I am not having much luck with this.

I guess the other alternative is to somehow apply a class within the foreach to the SVG file?

the foreach code:

```
 <? foreach($products as $product){?>
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3 product-outer" style="background-color:<?=$product['product_main_bg_colour'].';';?>">
                    <div>
                        <div class="product-box">
                            <div class="product-image"><img src="/<?=$product['product_thumbnail_image'];?>" alt="<?=$product['product_name'];?>" /></div>
                            <div class="product-name"><?=$product['product_name'];?></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="product-options" style="color:<?=$product['product_main_bg_colour'].';';?>">
                            <div class="option-list">
                                <div class="installation option-list-item"><?=file_get_contents(url()."/images/svgs/installation.svg");?>Installation help</div>
                                <div class="manual option-list-item"><?=file_get_contents(url()."/images/svgs/manual.svg");?>Download manual</div>
                                <div class="videos option-list-item"><?=file_get_contents(url()."/images/svgs/how-to.svg");?>How-to video</div>
                                <div class="troubleshoot option-list-item"><?=file_get_contents(url()."/images/svgs/troubleshoot.svg");?>Troubleshoot</div>
                                <div class="dimensions option-list-item"><?=file_get_contents(url()."/images/svgs/dimensions.svg");?>Dimensions</div>
                                <div class="more">View more</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <? }?>
```

Comment: Do you have any code you could show?

Comment: i have added the code generated by the foreach. the SVGs need colour changing in the option-list

Comment: How about color:parent AND fill:currentColor

Comment: fill:currentColor has worked!!! i had no idead about this option. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use color:parent in conjunction with fill:currentColor